# How to Web Scrape muliple JavaScript Rendered Pages with Ruby on Rails and Watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, webdriver, watir

This is the page I am trying to get the results of

```
https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?sourceContext=carGurusHomePage_false_0&formSourceTag=104&entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity=m2&zip=48126#resultsPage=1
```

Because the search results are rendered by JavaScript, I need to use the WebDriver Watir. I want to get the results of the first 5 pages. However, when I can only get the first page only and not other pages. How do I visit the other pages?

```
    $pageCount = 1

5.times do  
                page = $pageCount.to_s
                browser = Watir::Browser.start("https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?sourceContext=carGurusHomePage_false_0&formSourceTag=104&entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity=m2&zip=48126#resultsPage=#{page}", browser = :phantomjs)
                #browser.link(:class, "nextPageElement").wait_until_present
                doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
                    entries = doc.css('.cg-dealFinder-result-wrap')
                    entries.each do |entry|
                          title = entry.css('.cg-dealFinder-result-model>span')[0].text.strip
                          link = entry.css('.cg-dealFinder-result-stats>p>span')[0].text.strip
                          newEntry = Entry.new(title: title, description:link)
                          if title.present? && link.present? && Entry.where(title: title, description: link).blank?
                             newEntry.save
                          end
                    end
                $pageCount = $pageCount + 1
                browser.close
        end
```

Btw I am able to successfully web scrape multiple for other websites that have non-JavaScript rendered page results.

Comment: How about parsing the json response for the underlying request? Look for the request `ajaxFetchSubsetInventoryListing` right after the page is loaded. The URL you posted builds an Ajax POST request with the correspondent params.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a range (or array) that represents the number of pages, you can iterate and pass the page number to the `Browser::goto` method plus scrape the page using the `Browser::html` method or target whatever data you're looking to collect.

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

(1..5).each do |num|
  b.goto "https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?sourceContext=carGurusHomePage_false_0&formSourceTag=104&entitySelectingHelper.selectedEntity=m2&zip=48126#resultsPage=#{num}"
  puts b.div(:id => "displayedListingsCount").text   # or puts b.html
end    
b.close

#=> Showing 1 - 15 out of 2000 listings
#=> Showing 16 - 30 out of 2000 listings
#=> Showing 31 - 45 out of 2000 listings
#=> Showing 46 - 60 out of 2000 listings
#=> Showing 61 - 75 out of 2000 listings
```